# Microstack - Can't login to dashboard as admin

Tags: openstack

> An error occurred authenticating. Please try again later.

Can't find any keystone logs, and most fixes are from years ago. Where do I start with this error? How does one restart openstack/microstack services? Everything I've tried from forums results in service not found.